# How to define the path of a file which is inside my workspace in the properties file

Tags: java, spring

I need to read a jks(java key stroke) file. I have kept the file in the resource directory of my java spring mvc workspace. I have defined the file path in a properties file. But the problem is I am unable to give the correct file path. 
When I am specifying the path as C:/Users/Workspace/projectworkspace/..../resources/xyz.jks
it is able to locate. But when I give the relative path, the "/" converts to "\". What am I doing wrong and how to give the relative path in the properties file.

Comment: Did you try "\\" delimiter ?

Comment: yes. \\ converts to \.... opposite to what i need.

Comment: Maybe you can show a properties file fragment, and code where you use it.

Comment: Do you really have 4 "." that is "...." and not ".." in the path. I not on windows, but don't know if that path will get resolved